# JUnit UnsatisfiedLinkError

Tags: junit, unsatisfiedlinkerror

I'm running a simple JUnit Test and in its execution I got this error:

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no jmupdf64 in java.library.path
```

any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add this JVM option:

```
-Djava.library.path="<the directory of jmupdf64>"
```

For Mac OSX:
You need to create `libjmupdf64.dylib`

1. Download source code from: http://code.google.com/p/jmupdf/downloads/list
2. Commenting out Line#67 file: `./thirdparty/tifflib/tif_config.h`:

   `// #define lfind _lfind`
3. Need to more settings for OSX:

   - Add JNI header files to `CFLAGS` in ./Makefile.
   - Change `JNI_DLL` to `libjmupdf64.dylib`.
   - etc...
4. Make lib:

   `$ make`

Comment: I tried this.

FIRST: Run Configurations / (x) = Arguments
SECOND: -Djava.library.path=/lib

But nothing work.

Comment: @RicardoGonzales Does it work if not a JUnit test? `/lib` is a real path?

Comment: Yes, you are right it's not working at all, it suppose "jmupdf64.jar" is calling a native library "libjmupdf64.so" I have that library in, lib, then I placed at the root of the project even I just point the native library reference but nothing is working :(

Comment: Note: The problem is only in MAC

Comment: @RicardoGonzales I edited the answer for Mac OSX. I can make the lib for mac osx But I don't know I can share the file..

Comment: Thank you I'm going to tested tomorrow.

Comment: Nope, It's not working, in linux and windows works very fine, but no in MAC OSX.

I've already try with the library path, add as native library but nothing is working. Maybe I'm missing where should put exactly your dynamic lib.

Comment: @RicardoGonzales Can you give me the result of `uname -v`?

Comment: @RicardoGonzales I created new lib: http://bitly.com/Wv8OyS (I run the sample code and work file.